# What does "gajo" mean as a musical directive on sheet music

Tags: terminology

One of the pieces in the current [ABRSM Grade 7 violin pieces](http://gb.abrsm.org/fileadmin/user_upload/syllabuses/violin0712.pdf) is Moritz Moszkowski's Spanischer Tanz No. 2 from his Spanische Tänze Op. 12. At the start of bar 49 is the marking "gajo".

[image: Photo of gajo bar]

According to the interwebs this is Spanish for a segment of citrus fruit. The bar it is on is the start of the middle section of the piece, where we move from G minor to G major. How do I play this like a segment of citrus fruit? What does this directive mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this context, the word "gajo" means joyful or merry. The composer seems to want you to underline the shift to G Major by playing in a noticeably more exuberant style. In most styles of tonal music, the shift from minor to major already implies a change of mood along those lines, but "merry" is a nicely evocative description of the precise shade of "happier" that the shift brings.

Answer (score 4):

To add to [the excellent answer by @PatMuchmore](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/23607/2125), "gajo" has nothing to do with fruit, it is but a slightly antiquated spelling for the Italian "gaio", which means "gay" (which is incidentaly a cognate word), whose interpretative meaning is self-explaining: play gayly :)